# Bulk Find Tool?

Tags: coding-style, find

I'm looking to do some directory cleanup to a 300+ page web app that is 10+ year old.  It contains a mix of classic .asp and .NET code and .xsl files.  It is a convoluted mess of spaghetti code as you can imagine.

What I would like to find is a tool where I can enter a list of file names and have the tool search for instances of the file name within the source of a given directory and report back counts for each file. I've been using [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?page=download&type=agentransack) to search on each file one at a time but as you can imagine it is very time consuming.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How long is "very time consuming"? You have only 300 files? It should be really fast.  Why can't you use grep to do most of this?

Comment: @Ira Baxter - Sorry should have titled this post Bulk Find Tool.

Comment: @Ira Baxter - Actually I'm probably selling myself short on the number of pages.  There's actually 4904 files contained within directories that compose the site excluding the image directory which is easily as big or bigger.  I know there are quite a few files within the directory that are no longer called anywhere.

Comment: [Edited your title to match what you said]. So what you really want to do is identify files that don't have any references from other files? How do you know the application doesn't manufacture page (file) names using say JavaScript?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply extract all the <a href=".."> tags, sort that list, delete duplicates and see which files are referenced? grep could do the extract step easily.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but Notepad++ has a "Find in Files" feature. It lets you use regex, optionally replace, filter results, and specify a directory. Hit find all, and it comes back with a list of locations of hits.

Comment: Yeah, that is the same thing Agent Ransack does, which by the way is an excellent tool.  What I need is something I can input "Filename1.htm, Filename2.asp,...,Filename4909.aspx" point it at a directory and get a count back for each file inputted. In this way I'll be able to track down orphaned files within the directory.